# C++: general thoughts about overloading operator new

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, new-operator

Have you overloaded `operator new` in C++?

If yes, why?

An interview question, for which I humbly request some of your thoughts.

Comment: 'no' is the simplest correct answer.

Comment: @SP: while in general it's better to avoid doing that, there are some legitimate cases, as the other answers explain.

Comment: @Matteo Italia It's still a correct answer as the question was asking _if_ _you_ had ever overloaded the new operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had an embedded system where `new` was only rarely allowed, and the memory could never be deleted, as we had to prove a maximum heap usage for reliability reasons.

We had a third party library developer who didn't like those rules, so they overloaded `new` and `delete` to work against a chunk of memory we allocated just for them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Overloading operator new gives you a chance to control where an object lives in memory. I did this because I knew some details about the lifetime of my objects, and wanted to avoid fragmentation on a platform which didn't have virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

You would overload `new` if you're using your own allocator, doing something fancy with reference counting, instrumenting for garbage collection, debugging object lifetimes or something else entirely; you're replacing the allocator for objects. I've personally had to do it to ensure certain objects get allocated on specific mmap'ed pages of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for two reasons: Custom allocator, and custom allocation tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading new operator may look as a good idea at first glance if you want to do custom allocation for some reason (i.e. avoiding memory fragmentation intrinsic to c-runtime allocator or/and avoiding locks on memory management calls in multithreaded programs). But when you get to implementation you may realize that in most cases you want to pass some additional context to this call, for example a thread-specific heap for objects of a given size. And overloading of new/delete simply doesn't work here. So eventually you may want to create your own facade to your custom memory management subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

I found it very handy to overload `operator new` when writing Python extension code in C++. I wrapped the Python C-API code for allocation and deallocation in `operator new` and `operator delete` overloads, respectively – this allows for `PyObject*`-compatible structures that can be created with `new MyType()` and managed with predictable heap-allocation semantics.

It also allows for a separation of the allocation code (normally in the Python `__new__` method) and the initialization code (in Python’s `__init__`) into, respectively, the `operator new` overloads and any constructors one sees fit to define.

Here’s a sample:

```cpp
struct ModelObject {

    static PyTypeObject* type_ptr() { return &ModelObject_Type; }

    /// operator new performs the role of tp_alloc / __new__
    /// Not using the 'new size' value here
    void* operator new(std::size_t) {
        PyTypeObject* type = type_ptr();
        ModelObject* self = reinterpret_cast<ModelObject*>(
            type->tp_alloc(type, 0));
        if (self != NULL) {
            self->weakrefs = NULL;
            self->internal = std::make_unique<buffer_t>(nullptr);
        }
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(self);
    }

    /// operator delete acts as our tp_dealloc
    void operator delete(void* voidself) {
        ModelObject* self = reinterpret_cast<ModelObject*>(voidself);
        PyObject* pyself = reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(voidself);
        if (self->weakrefs != NULL) { PyObject_ClearWeakRefs(pyself); }
        self->cleanup();
        type_ptr()->tp_free(pyself);
    }

    /// Data members
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject* weakrefs = nullptr;
    bool clean = false;
    std::unique_ptr<buffer_t> internal;

    /// Constructors fill in data members, analagous to __init__
    ModelObject()
        :internal(std::make_unique<buffer_t>())
        ,accessor{}
        {}

    explicit ModelObject(buffer_t* buffer)
        :clean(true)
        ,internal(std::make_unique<buffer_t>(buffer))
        {}

    ModelObject(ModelObject const& other)
        :internal(im::buffer::heapcopy(other.internal.get()))
        {}

    /// No virtual methods are defined to keep the struct as a POD
    /// ... instead of using destructors I defined a 'cleanup()' method:
    void cleanup(bool force = false) {
        if (clean && !force) {
            internal.release();
        } else {
            internal.reset(nullptr);
            clean = !force;
        }
    }

    /* … */

};
```